# How to map a non-zero index to each character in a string

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

```
alphabet = "AABBBCCCCDDDDDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZZZZZ"
```

I want to list the index of a character each time it occurs. However, for my purposes the initial starting index will be 1 instead of 0. I  managed to do that for a single character with this line:

```
list_all_Z = alphabet.chars.each_with_index.select{|indexx,| indexx.eql? "Z" }.map(&:last).map{|get_rid_of_zero,| get_rid_of_zero + 1 }
```

Which outputs:

```
print "all the Z's #{list_all_Z}" --> all the Z's [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]
```

How can I accomplish the same task but for every letter in the sequence without manually entering in every specific character at

```
indexx.eql?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way to do that:

```
alphabet = "AABBBCCCCDDDDDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZZZZZ"

h = alphabet.each_char.
             with_index(1).
             group_by(&:first).
             transform_values { |a| a.map(&:last) }
  #=> {"A"=>[1, 2], "B"=>[3, 4, 5], "C"=>[6, 7, 8, 9],
  #    "D"=>[10, 11, 12, 13, 14], "E"=>[15], "F"=>[16], "G"=>[17],
  #    "H"=>[18], "I"=>[19], "J"=>[20], "K"=>[21], "L"=>[22], "M"=>[23],
  #    "N"=>[24], "O"=>[25], "P"=>[26], "Q"=>[27], "R"=>[28], "S"=>[29],
  #    "T"=>[30], "U"=>[31], "V"=>[32], "W"=>[33], "X"=>[34], "Y"=>[35],
  #    "Z"=>[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]} 

c = 'Z'
puts "All the #{c}'s: #{h[c]}"
All the Z's: [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]
```

The steps are as follows:

```
a = alphabet.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator:"AABBB...ZZZZZZ":each_char> 
b = a.with_index(1)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "AABBB...ZZZZZZ":each_char>:with_index(1)> 
c = b.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"A"=>[["A", 1], ["A", 2]],
  #    "B"=>[["B", 3], ["B", 4], ["B", 5]],
  #    ...
  #    "Z"=>[["Z", 36], ["Z", 37], ["Z", 38], ["Z", 39], ["Z", 40],
  #          ["Z", 41]]}
```

`b.group_by(&:first)` is more-or-less shorthand for:

```
c = b.group_by { |c,i| c }
```

Lastly:

```
c.transform_values { |a| a.map(&:last) }
  #=> <as above>
```

Note:

```
a.next #=> "A"
a.next #=> "A"
a.next #=> "A"
a.next #=> "B"
...
```

and

```
b.next #=> ["A", 1] 
b.next #=> ["A", 2]
b.next #=> ["B", 3] 
b.next #=> ["B", 4] 
...
```

The elements generated by the enumerator `b` are passed to `group_by`'s block, `{ |c,i| c }`, and the block variables are assigned to their values. For example:

```
b.rewind
c, i = b.next #=> ["A", 1] 
c             #=> "A" 
i             #=> 1
```

See [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index), [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#rewind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind).

Comment: An alternative for `.group_by(&:first).transform_values { |a| a.map(&:last) }` is `.group_by(&:shift).transform_values(&:flatten)`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, `first()` is more precise than `shift()` in this case and `flatten()` is not correct. `[["A", 1], ["A", 2]].flatten #=> ["A", 0, "A", 1]`

Comment: @Thang, you are forgetting that `shift` is destructive. It’s `[[1], [2]].flatten #=> [1, 2]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I see it now, should have tested it full instead of just the replacements `flatten`. Sorry @3limin4t0r

Answer (score 1):

```rb
count_all =
  alphabet.
  chars.
  each.
  with_index(1).                   # start with 1
  with_object({}) do |(c, i), acc| # collect
    (acc[c] ||= []) << i
  end
```

The above will collect a hash, mapping symbols to their indices, `1`-based.

The accumulator might be smarter; three last lines might look like:

```rb
  with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |(c, i), acc|
    acc[c] << i
  end
```

Comment: A small, ephemeral suggestion: `each_char`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I honestly try to avoid syntactic sugar when it brings even no keystroke savings :)

Comment: `"chars.each.".size #=> 11; "each_char.".size #=> 10`!! (...and `each_char` avoids the creation of a temporary array).

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep simple so my brain can handle it. I'd do this:

```
str = "AABBBCCCCDDDDDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZZZZZZ"

idx = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
str.chars
  .each_with_index { |c, i|
    idx[c] << 1 + i
  }
```

Which results in:

```
idx
# => {"A"=>[1, 2],
#     "B"=>[3, 4, 5],
#     "C"=>[6, 7, 8, 9],
#     "D"=>[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#     "E"=>[15],
#     "F"=>[16],
#     "G"=>[17],
#     "H"=>[18],
#     "I"=>[19],
#     "J"=>[20],
#     "K"=>[21],
#     "L"=>[22],
#     "M"=>[23],
#     "N"=>[24],
#     "O"=>[25],
#     "P"=>[26],
#     "Q"=>[27],
#     "R"=>[28],
#     "S"=>[29],
#     "T"=>[30],
#     "U"=>[31],
#     "V"=>[32],
#     "W"=>[33],
#     "X"=>[34],
#     "Y"=>[35],
#     "Z"=>[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]}
```

Alternately it could be written using `each.with_index(1)` instead of `each_with_index` and not having to assign the index + 1 each time:

```
str.chars
  .each.with_index(1) { |c, i|
    idx[c] << i
  }
```

which results in the same hash, or:

```
idx = str.chars
  .each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] })
  .with_index(1) { |(c, h), i|
    h[c] << i
  }
```

which moves the definition of the accumulating object into the `each_with_object` initialization. I think it's a little more visually noisy, but YMMV.